# Method merge() change "createDate" field in database to "null" in Hibernate + Spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, merge

I have a SpringBoot + Hibernate web project.

This is my "Course" entity

```
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedDate;
    
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    ...
}
```

This is my "CourseRepository"

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CourseRepository {
    
    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;
    
    public Course save(Course course) {
            em.merge(course);
    }
    ... 
}
```

This is my data.sql (insert data for database)

```
insert into course(id, name, created_date, last_updated_date) values (10001, 'abc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
insert into course(id, name, created_date, last_updated_date) values (10002, 'abc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
insert into course(id, name, created_date, last_updated_date) values (10003, 'abc', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

This is my "DemoApplication"

```
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository repository;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        repository.save(new Course(10002L, "abcdefghfi"));
    }
}
```

When I run the application and check in H2 database, this is table "Course"

| ID | CREATED_DATE | LAST_UPDATED_DATE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-11-02 23:13:51.926762 | 2022-11-02 23:13:51.926762 | abc |
| 10002 | null | 2022-11-02 23:13:52.325534 | abcdefghfi |
| 10003 | 2022-11-02 23:13:51.930761 | 2022-11-02 23:13:51.930761 | abc |

I don't know why create date of course 10002 is null. Can anyone help me, please?

#More info: When I change 10002L in DemoApplication to 1L(an Id not exist in database) an rerun. A new record was inserted in database with create_date not null

Comment: I may not be correct here, however I believe those annotations are hibernate based, and while Spring may support them (as it does many hibernate annotations) it may not be working exactly as expected. Spring does however have its own implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing. In short, try `@CreatedDate`, and `@LastModifiedDate`. Want to add, if you'd like more control you can alternatively use `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` as can be seen here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle-events good luck!

Comment: @TedEllis I tried your solution, but now, both "create_date" and "last_updated_date" are null :(

Comment: private Timestamp createdDate; - use the java sql timestamp

Comment: @VasimHayat I tried your solution, "create_date" still null :(

Comment: I think the reason is passing a new object to method merge(). But I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Your em.merge is telling the entity manager that a field should be updated, not created new. We can gain some insight into how your save method may look by looking at Spring Boots JPARepository.save implementation.

Since you are using Spring Boot, you may also want to look at how their repositories work so you do not have to recreate the wheel so to speak. However, the below code on implementing a function to both create a new, and merge an entity should sufficiently solve your issue.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

For further reading here is an article on Spring Boots JPARepository if you would like to migrate to it, the article is more in depth that just a JPARepository, but is good regardless.

https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

To migrate to JPARepository your code for the repository would look like

```
@Repository
public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {

}
```

You can then @Autowire CourseRepository in and call the built in .save method without writing any code.

Note: the above relies on having a spring-data-jpa dependency, similar to the below for maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I can understand your solution with Spring Data JPA. But now, I 'm trying with Hibernate only.  em.merge is telling the entity manager that a field should be updated, not created new. So, create _date must have value and must not changed to null

Comment: Yes, so the original issue of the created timestamp not being set is because the entity is being merged, not persisted. Unless I am misunderstanding.

The first codeblock I have displayed should show a solution for hibernate only, where when the entity is created new the persist method is called and your annotation for creationtimestamp should complete.

Comment: Ah! I have to apologize I just noticed you are initially creating that data via sql insertion... and then the created timestamp is being stripped off after you try to merge... I am sorry I missed that! Hopefully someone with a bit more knowledge on direct hibernate can pop by, but I believe by creating a new course instead of selecting the course you want to update first, and then modifying the entity that is returned from your db, is the source of your problem. when you pass a new course into merge, the new course has a null createdtimestamp, and updated timestamp but updated is reset onmerge

Comment: Yes, so I shoud call find() method to get an object from database, then modify this object and call merge() to update to database?

Comment: I believe that is the correct approach. There may be some tricks to only merge certain fields, or set a trigger in the db to not update the created date field if the incoming data is null, but this would not be a usual approach.